# intellisense cannot open source file " .tlb" in C++

Tags: c++

Iam tring to deploy my C# dll in C++, by converting it .tlb. But, while im importing it into C++ program, using the statement

```
#import "MyProject.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only
```

Iam geting the error

```
intellisense cannot open source file " c:/.../debug/MyProject.tlh"  
bad descriptor for file.
```

Also getting the warning:

```
#import  skipped when looking for precompiled header use
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do a wrapper to access the C# library. For that you must create a header file which will contain the interface header for the library:

```
#include "YC#library_interface.hpp"
```

And you also need to implement the wrapper to do it ([SWIG ???](http://www.swig.org/))

Comment: The simpler may be to implement your library in c++ as well.